# How to convert a dynamic column to a static column in Apache Phoenix?

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have a table, MY_T, where I have been adding some data to a dynamic column, COL_D. This works fine and I even have a view for easy access to COL_D. After some time I realized that COL_D is generic enough to apply to all rows so I wanted to make it a fixed part of the table.

```
alter table MY_T add COL_D INTEGER
```

But this doesn't work.

```
ERROR 1010 (42M01): Not allowed to mutate table.
  Cannot drop column referenced by VIEW columnName=MY_T
  [SQL State=42M01, DB Errorcode=1010]
```

I tried dropping the column from the view (that worked) but it still can't be added to the table.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm using Phoenix 4.4.0 as part of HDP 2.4.2 (if that matters).